# Why is the CSV Layer converting a Date-Time field to Unix Timestamps?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, csv

I am using the ArcGIS JavaScript API to add a dynamic map in my application. I am loading data through a csvLayer.

The data looks something like this:
[image]

Here's a snippet of me initiating the csvLayer:

```
var csvLayer = new CSVLayer({
                    url: numberLayers[0].Url,
                    popupTemplate: popupTemplate,
                    featureReduction: {
                        type: "selection"
                    },
                });
```

The Popup template where I am displaying the information from the CSV file is given here:

```
var popupTemplate = {
                    title: "{SensorTitle}",
                    content:
                        [
                            {
                                type: "fields",
                                fieldInfos: [
                                    { fieldName: "DateTime", label: "Date" },
                                    { fieldName: "Temp", label: "Temperature (°F)" },
                                    { fieldName: "Humidity", label: "Humidity (%)" },
                                    { fieldName: "DewPoint", label: "Dew Point (°F)" },
                                    { fieldName: "PM1", label: "PM 1.0 (µg/m3)" },
                                    { fieldName: "PM25", label: "PM 2.5 (µg/m3)" },
                                    { fieldName: "PM10", label: "PM 10.0 (µg/m3)" },
                                    { fieldName: "O3", label: "Ozone (ppb)" },
                                    { fieldName: "NO2", label: "Nitrogen Dioxide (ppb)" },
                                    { fieldName: "CO", label: "Carbon Monoxide (ppb)" },
                                ]
                            },
                        ],
                    actions:
                        [
                            { title: "More Information", id: "more-info", className: "esri-icon-notice-round" }
                        ],
                    overwriteActions: true,
                };
```

Now this is how the data is presented on my application:
[image]

If you notice the datetime field for some reason changes automatically from a normal timestamp format to Unix epoch times. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

P.S: If this post is not clear enough, just compare the two images I posted. The datetime field is automatically changing into a different format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need a [FieldInfoFormat](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-popup-support-FieldInfoFormat.html#dateFormat) object as follows:

```
var myFormat = new FieldInfoFormat({ 
dateFormat: "short-date-short-time"})
```

...then later in the fieldInfos[] of your popupTemplate, the date field should be supplemented with this formatter...

```
 fieldInfos: [
      { fieldName: "DateTime", label: "Date",     format: myFormat},
      { fieldName: "Temp", label: "Temperature (°F)" },
      { fieldName: "Humidity", label: "Humidity (%)" },
      { fieldName: "DewPoint", label: "Dew Point (°F)" },
      { fieldName: "PM1", label: "PM 1.0 (µg/m3)" },
      { fieldName: "PM25", label: "PM 2.5 (µg/m3)" },
      { fieldName: "PM10", label: "PM 10.0 (µg/m3)" },
      { fieldName: "O3", label: "Ozone (ppb)" },
      { fieldName: "NO2", label: "Nitrogen Dioxide (ppb)" },
      { fieldName: "CO", label: "Carbon Monoxide (ppb)" }
    ]
```

Note that this formatter may or may not be UTC-aware by default as the epoch-milliseconds value incoming from your csvLayer, so you may have to adjust to that using the [intl module](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-intl.html).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have fixed the problem. Have a good day!!